# Tiny orange yellow bug in raspberries? What is it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, food

There's a tiny orange yellow bug in raspberries:

[image]

What is it? The fruit was sitting in the fridge for 3 days

Comment: What country do you live in?  That might help to narrow it down.

Comment: I've often seen something very similar to this, only reddish-brown.  (Not particularly on fruit.)  Shiny, about 2-3 mm long.  That's in the UK.  So I'd like to know the answer, too!

Answer (score -2):

chances are it is an "aphid"
https://influentialpoints.com/Gallery/Amphorophora_idaei_Large_raspberry_aphid.htm

take a look here
https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=883

here,
https://www.extension.iastate.edu/news/yard-and-garden-insect-pests-raspberry-fruit

Raspberry's are yummy and there is a lot of competition!

Comment: body shape and size are wrong. I'm guessing it's a mite of some kind.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. Also note that answers must be self-contained (must not require following links). ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you.